# Why is model unidentifiability a problem?

Tags: identifiability, bradley-terry-model

I am new to the concept of model identifiability, but from my understanding it is possible to learn the true parameter values of the model after obtaining an infinite number of observations from it. In my case, I am looking at the Bradley-Terry model for collaborative filtering discussed in [Bradley-Terry](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7837931/), where the authors state that model unidentifiability is indeed a problem, however I do not see a reason for that.

If the model exhibits the same performance for different sets of parameters, why is it important that the true parameters is not strictly determined?